# Axiom of choice and function with empty codomain

Tags: axiom-of-choice

I'm having a little problem here, namely if the axiom of choice ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Statement)) is

$$\forall X \left[ \emptyset \notin X \implies \exists f: X \to \bigcup X \quad \forall A \in X \, ( f(A) \in A ) \right]$$

and I choose the nonempty $X=\{\emptyset\}\neq \emptyset$ for which only $\emptyset\in X$ and hence $A=\emptyset$, then I get

$$\exists f:\{\emptyset\}\to\emptyset\ \  \text{such that}\ \  f(\emptyset) \in \emptyset.$$

The last point seems wrong in itself though. Of course, there is no actual value $f(\emptyset)$, so $f(\emptyset) \in \emptyset$ doesn't say much. It might be just taken to be a legal statement. I haven't seen that written down anywhere though.

Comment: I don't think $\emptyset\notin\{\emptyset\}$ is true (see the left hand side of $\Rightarrow$). An implication where the left hand side is false is automatically true.

Comment: @celtschk: You're right, thanks. I somehow read the condition to be $\emptyset \neq X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $X=\{\varnothing\}$ satisfies the statement vacuously, so it's fine. You can change the statement to the following:

$$\forall X\exists f\left[f\colon X\to\bigcup X\cup\{\varnothing\}\land\forall A\in X(f(A)\in A\lor A=\varnothing)\right]$$

It allows $\varnothing\in X$, and therefore $X=\{\varnothing\}$. But it's harder to understand it this way, so it's easier to just require $\varnothing\notin X$.

Comment: k, thanks for the addition information. Is there a reason you prefer \varnothing over \emptyset and is there really a point to \colon?

Comment: Nick, $\varnothing$ over $\emptyset$ is just a typographical choice. `\colon over `:` is a choice between a separator and a symbol, note that $f:X$ (`:`) and $f\colon X$ (`\colon`) have different spacings.

Comment: I know, I saw someone correcting Terry Tao on his blog once, and he thanked that guy. I don't see why $f\colon X$ would be better than $f:X$ though, I feel the second one is somewhat clearer.

Comment: TeX.SE: [Using \colon or : in formulas?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas)